# How do you cache a menu when loading it programmatically?

Tags: 7, navigation, caching

I am having the below code to load the main menu tree.

```
$tree = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');
  $parentMenu = array();
  $index = 0;
  foreach($tree as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value['link']['hidden'])) {
      continue;
    }
    $submenu = array();
    foreach($value['below'] as $subMenu) {
      if (!empty($subMenu['link']['hidden'])) {
        continue;
      }
      $tid = explode('/', $subMenu['link']['link_path']);
      $submenu[]= array(
        'link_title' => $subMenu['link']['link_title'],
        'link_path' => drupal_get_path_alias($subMenu['link']['link_path']),
        'link_tid' => $tid,
      );
    }
    $parentMenu[$index]['link_title'] = $value['link']['link_title'];
    $parentMenu[$index]['link_path'] = drupal_get_path_alias($value['link']['link_path']);
    $tidSubmenus = explode('/', $value['link']['link_path']);
    $parentMenu[$index]['link_tid'] = $tidSubmenus[2];
    $parentMenu[$index]['sub_menu'] = $submenu;

    $index++;
  }
  $vars['parentMenu'] = $parentMenu;
```

Here, into the variable, $parentMenu I am storing the main menu tree. After that
i am printing the menu structure using below code in template.

```
 <?php if ($parentMenu): ?>
   //printing the html structure
   <?php foreach($parentMenu as $mainMenu) { ?>
     //printing the html structure
     <?php foreach($mainMenu['sub_menu'] as $k => $childMenu) { ?>
        <?php print $childMenu['link_title']; ?> 
            <?php
              //printing the html structure
               $recent_content = views_embed_view('masala_taxonomy_section','block_10', $childMenu['link_tid'][2]);
                print $recent_content;
            ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This is taking too long to store the home page and other page... am I missing anything here... or is there need to optimize the code?

Comment: Have you got quite a big menu structure? I see you're only displaying the first 2 levels aren't you? With `menu_tree_all_data` you're loading the full menu structure so if its a large menu that will be a slow call in itself. You can pass a 2nd parameter to that function with the depth .e.g `$tree = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu',2);`

Comment: For caching it, cache_set/cache_get on your array. Also, only grab the menu you need, as Leigh said.